# Use right syntax error in Mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Am not able to fix the error below:

> `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'When,Then) values(  '79','WBT-CoE','gyj','yi','yi')' at line 1"` error.

Here's the code:

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        string MyconnectionString = "server=localhost;database=requirement_doc;Uid=t;Pwd=123;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyconnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd;

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  Req_ID, Actor FROM UseCase where Req_ID='" + txtReqID.Text + "' AND Actor='" + DropDownList1.Text + "'";
                    MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da1.Fill(dt1);

        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            Label1.Text = "Data already exist";

        }


        else
        {


            string sql = "INSERT INTO UseCase (Req_ID,Actor,Given,When,Then) values(  '" + txtReqID.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + giventxt.Text + "','" + whentbl.Text + "','" + thentbl.Text + "')"; 

                          cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            conn.Open();



        }
        try
        {

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = " Successfully saved";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 2):

Surround When and then with `` because they are reserved names.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO UseCase (Req_ID,Actor,Given,`When`,`Then`) values(  '" + txtReqID.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + giventxt.Text + "','" + whentbl.Text + "','" + thentbl.Text + "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

`When` and `Then` are reserved names in MySQL. So if you use those as column names, you get that error.